# Using repeat() with auto-fit & minmax: is there a max-width for 1fr?

Tags: css, grid, minmax

I'm using the declaration **grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));** and it works like it's supposed to, but I'd like to have a max-width for 1fr - is there a way to limit the width resulting from 1fr to, say, 450px?

I know there's min(), max() and clamp(), but the support for those doesn't seem to be that good yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `min()`, `max()` and `clamp()` are not allowed inside the `repeat()` function  (right now), the only option is to set the `max-width` to the direct children, using a global selector like `.Grid > *`. But note that you will have to handle the alignment of the cells.